# Codeigniter redirect points to wrong address

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect

I use codeigniter and this is my redirecting function:

```
$this->load->helper('url');
redirect(base_url('main'));
```

It works properly when I am trying on my PC where the webserver is running but when I am connecting to my computer's webserver from another device then this points to localhost.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is ` $config['base_url']` set as in /application/config/config.php?

Comment: Thank you for your post, that was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In order to have a correct relation passes you need to configure your virtual host:

```
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/"
    ServerName localhost
    ErrorLog  "c:/wamp/logs/apache_error.log"
    CustomLog "c:/wamp/logs/access.log" common
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost 192.168.1.2:80  127.0.0.1:80>
    DocumentRoot "D:/SVN/joomla/"
    ServerName joomla
    ErrorLog "c:/wamp/logs/joomla_error.log"
    CustomLog "c:/wamp/logs/joomla_access.log" common
<Directory "D:/SVN/joomla/">
      AllowOverride all

          Order Allow,Deny
      Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

So your project will be available via local net by IP 192.168.1.2
So you will write http://192.168.1.2/myproj

Also in a httpd.conf 
Listen 127.0.0.1:80 192.168.1.2:80

Comment: Thank you for your information but the problem was that the baseurl pointed to localhost.

Comment: this is it. if the environment via virtual hosts will point to the external ip the baseurl will return right value. localhost it's just alias for 127.0.0.1